# Print float or double in non scientific notaion

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, scientific-notation

Float or double always gives answer in scientific notation if number of digits are 7 or more. Like an decimal number `10000000.5` it is giving `1e-08` something. I am wondering if we can print `10000000.5` without adding any new header file.

Comment: How are you printing the number?

Comment: i was trying to print using cout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are printing to `cout`, use

```
std::cout.setf( std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield );
```

[See it work.](http://ideone.com/pwjUoG)

You might also want `std::cout.precision(1)` to set the number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%.1f", someFloat)` should do that for you, if you want one decimal digit. If you want `n` decimal digits, then use `%.nf`

Comment: To be clear, the `n` in `%nf` is not a literal `n`. If the number of digits is variable, you can use `printf("%.*f", n, someFloat)`

Comment: yes, that is just an example...i hope i was able to make it clear in the answer..thanks

Comment: Thanks. This one too Helpful